# Javascript query not returning results from query to SharePoint list

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to return the contents of a SharePoint list to a HTML page using a JavaScript Query and json.

The two SharePoint columns are called Title and IssueID and are a Single line and Number column. I need it to return it to the Table cell '' in the HTML. I've attached a screen grab from Firefox debugger but I don't know where this is pointing? [Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5U88.png)

JavaScript:

```
function getDeviceKnownIssues() {

var txtTitle = "";


var query = "http://collaboration-dev.norgine.com/sites/it/SystemInventory/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Knownissues?$select=IssueID,Title"; 

var call = $.ajax({
        url: query,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }       
    });
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
$.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {

        var tempID = result.Id;
        var tempTitle = result.Title;
        txtTitle = txtTitle + "<p><a href='/sites/it/SystemInventory/SitePages/Service%20Catalogue.aspx?did=" + tempID + "'>" + tempTitle + "</a></p>";
        //txtStatus = "<p>" + StatusType  + "</p>";
    });
   $('#knowntitle').append($(txtTitle));
   //$('#servivestatus').append(txtStatus);

});
call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    alert("Error retrieving data: " + jqXHR.responseText);
});

}
```

HTML

```
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"      
xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"><head>

<script src="/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="/it/SystemInventory/SiteAssets/scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sites/it/SystemInventory/SiteAssets/getDevices.js"></script>
<script  
src="/sites/it/SystemInventory/SiteAssets/getDeviceDetails.js"></script>

 <script 
src="/sites/it/SystemInventory/SiteAssets/getDeviceKnownIssues.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function parseQueryString(queryString)
{
var params = {}, queries, temp, i, l;
queries = queryString.split("&");
for ( i = 0, l = queries.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    temp = queries[i].split('=');
    params[temp[0]] = temp[1];
 }
return params;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
function getDeviceID() {
    if(typeof parseQueryString === "function") {
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
            var qs = parseQueryString(window.location.href.split("?")[1])
            window.DeviceId = qs.did;
            getDeviceDetails();
            getDeviceKnownIssues();
        }
    }
}
getDeviceID();
getDevices();

 });


</script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-    style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
<tr>
 <td class="tg-yw4l">
    <h1>Devices</h1>
    <div id="devices">
    </div>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
    <h1>Device Details</h1>
    <div id="devicedetails">
    </div>
   </td>
   <td class="tg-yw4l">
<h1>Device Overview</h1> 
    <div id="deviceoverview">
     <div id="devicekind">   
    </div>
  </td>
  </tr>


</table>

<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
    <h1>Accessories</h1>
    <div id="deviceacc">

    </div>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
    <h1>Typical Usage</h1>

    <div id="deviceuse">
    </div>
    </td>
<td class="tg-yw4l">
<h1>Spare Cell</h1> 
    <div id=" ">



    </div>
</td>
</tr>




</table>
Known Issues
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
   <td class="tg-yw4l">
     <h1>Title</h1>
    <div id="knowntitle">

    </div>
</td>
<td class="tg-yw4l">
    <h1>Service Status</h1>

    <div id="servivestatus">
    </div>
</td>
<td class="tg-yw4l">
<h1>Device Type</h1> 
    <div id=" ">



    </div>
</td>
  </tr>




</table>
```

Comment: Something I've just realised is that I don't need the

 txtTitle = txtTitle + "<p><a href='/sites/it/SystemInventory/SitePages/Service%20Catalogue.aspx?did=" + tempID + "'>" + tempTitle + "</a></p>"; 

line as an earlier file is building that page, so I should just need

 txtTitle = "<p"> + KnownTitle + "</p>"; but it's still not showing up...?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your call.done method with the below code,

```
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
 var result = data.d.results;
$.each(result , function(index, item) {

        var tempID = result.Id;
        var tempTitle = result.Title;
        txtTitle = txtTitle + "<p><a href='/sites/it/SystemInventory/SitePages/Service%20Catalogue.aspx?did=" + tempID + "'>" + tempTitle + "</a></p>";
        //txtStatus = "<p>" + StatusType  + "</p>";
    });
   $('#knowntitle').append($(txtTitle));
   //$('#servivestatus').append(txtStatus);

});
```

Comment: by replacing this your result related error will be resolved and make sure you have HTML proper because that parent element related error in console is related to it.so verify your Html once again.

Comment: I replaced the call method, the results still don't show and I get the following in the debugger:

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: getDeviceKnownIssues is not defined
    at getDeviceID (Service%20Catalogue.aspx:878)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Service%20Catalogue.aspx:882)
    at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that there is also another JavaScript file that I'm using to get some other results. The revised call.done method knocked out some of the results which that file returned.

Comment: This error is also related to undefined variables make sure you have no undefined variables in js files.as i have updated result here by declaring it you have to do the same for your other variables.or you can read some articles on javascript.

Comment: I think you're right. I think it's down to:
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
 $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
            var KnownTitle = item.Title;

Am I iterating through the entire resultset and overriding the TxtTitleKnown ?